# Wake on LAN dont work on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS with Realtek r8168

Tags: server, 22.04, lts, realtek, wakeonlan

good, I'm running ubuntu server 22.04 LTS I have tried other distro's but I still can't solve my problem, I have a realtek 8111/8168/8411 integrated network card the problem is that I'm trying to make Wake on Lan work, I have tried several things, the ethetool -s eno1 wol g is always on g and it doesn't work. The port light is still on after turning off the computer, the problem is that for it to work I have to be the laptop without battery, remove the power for a second and put it back and then the wake on lan works without problem to the millisecond, but if I do not remove the power cable does not, this also happens when I turn off the computer when I exit the bios, the WoL works without problems and also when I turn off the computer from a Windows Live. But when I shut down the computer from Linux and I have tried a lot of different commands to shut down, I need to remove the power and put it back on for the wake on lan to work.

I have tried installing the r8168-dkmz package, I have also added the r8169 to the blacklist and I don't know what else to try anymore, in the bios the wake on lan options are the same whether they are enabled or not, the behavior is the same. I do not know if anyone has managed to solve this problem.